# php preg_match multiple groups at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex, match

I have a preg_match problem.
Here's the string

`field[0][price][8]`

And the regex

```
"/([\[]([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)?[\]])+$/"
```

I want to check if the string ends with one ore more [ ] and extract all the values inside.
When i put the `$` flag, `preg_match_all` only gets the big and the last found groups. Something similar happens with `preg_match`.

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '[0][price][8]' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '[8]' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
```

This is the desired result, that i get only if i omit the `$` flag, which is not ok because i need to check if the string ends with the matched pattern:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[0]' (length=3)
      1 => string '[price]' (length=7)
      2 => string '[8]' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[0]' (length=3)
      1 => string '[price]' (length=7)
      2 => string '[8]' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string 'price' (length=5)
      2 => string '8' (length=1)
```

---

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to be sure, would you like your example to only return `8` or `0` and `price` as well?

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the quick reply! I want it to return everything it finds at the end of the string between [ ]. So yeah, in this case i need it to return `0`, `price`, `8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to check if the string ends with the required format:

```
preg_match_all("/(?=.*(?:\[.*?])+$)\[(.*?)]/", $str, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

`(?:\[.*?])+` matches one or more `[xyz]` sections. The actual matching is performed only if the lookahead succeeds.

For the string in question, `$result` would contain:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "price"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```

Comment: @DănuțMihaiFlorian: The pattern might look a bit daunting when you're just starting out with lookarounds, but with practice and time, you'll be able to craft regexes easily. For an explanation, see [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS3oY4/1). If you're still confused about something, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

An other way using `strrev`:

```
$str = 'field[0][price][8]';

if (preg_match_all('~\G]([^[]*)\[~', strrev($str), $m))
    $result = array_map('strrev', $m[1]);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like writing `$match[0][$something[0]`, you can use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com):

```
pattern("([\[]([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)?[\]])+$")
    ->match('field[0][price][8]')
    ->first(function (Match $match) {

       $match->text();   // the matched occurrence

       $match->group(1); // group #1 of the match
    });
```